# Cannot read property 'json' of undefined problem in react native

Tags: react-native

I am working on API's in react native but i have an error ı cannot fix. I am trying to fetch data and convert it to json. That code worked in different project but now not working. Is anybody can fix it?
It's fetching and working but not show the data that i want. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YyjM1.png)

```js
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

function useFetch (url) {
    const [data, setData] = useState([]);
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState (true);
    const [error, setError] = useState();

    const fetchData = async () => {
        try {
            const {response} = await fetch(url);
            const convertedData = await response.json();
            setData(convertedData);
            setLoading(false);
        } catch (error) {
            setError(error.message);
            setLoading(false);
        }
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        fetchData();
    }, [])

    return {data, loading,error};
}


export default useFetch;
```

Comment: Did you have tried without the curly braces? Like this `const response = await fetch(url);`. Please provide the conlose.log() of the response both with and without curly braces.

Answer (score 1):

`fetch` returns a `Response` object which is a Readable Stream. So, we cant directly destructure it. Try this

```
const response = await fetch(url);
const convertedData = await response.json();
```

or can convert it to a single line as

```
const convertedData = await fetch(url).json();
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it! I needed to:

- Add the `url` parameter in `useEffect` function's dependencies
- Reset the data component of `flatlist` to `data.result`
- Add the `keyExtractor` and convert it to string.

When I did this, my problem was solved.

Comment: I'm glad you resolved it.  Consider also adding the fixed code in your answer do that future readers who have the same problem can see the final result. Thanks!